# How to load and save a work order record using the map reduce script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to only load and save a work order record using the map-reduce script. But I don't see logs for loaded work orders or saved work orders. the script is executing only until work_order_Id. Please Help!

Below is my code...

```
    function getInputData(){
    var process_data =[];
        try{
            var workorderSearchObj = search.create({
               type: "workorder",
               filters:
               [
                  ["type","anyof","WorkOrd"], 
                  "AND", 
                  ["mainline","is","T"], 
                  "AND", 
                  ["status","anyof","WorkOrd:A","WorkOrd:B","WorkOrd:D"]
               ],
               columns:
               [
                  search.createColumn({name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID"}),
                  search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"})
               ]
            });
            var searchResultCount = workorderSearchObj.runPaged().count;
            log.debug("workorderSearchObj result count",searchResultCount);
            workorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
               // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
               var work_Order = result.getValue({name:'internalid'});
               var document_no = result.getValue({name:'tranid'});
               process_data.push({
                'work_Order':work_Order,
                'document_no':document_no
            });
               return true;
            });
            
        
        }catch(error){
            log.debug(error);
        }   
            return process_data;
    }
     function map(context){
        var process_data=JSON.parse(context.value);
        log.debug('process_data',process_data);
        var work_order_Id = process_data.work_Order;
        log.debug("work_order_Id",work_order_Id);
        var work_Order_obj = record.load({
            type: record.Type.WORK_ORDER,
            id: work_order_Id,
            isDynamic: true
        }); 
       log.debug("work_Order_obj",work_Order_obj);
        var recId=work_Order_obj.save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: true
        });
       log.debug("recId",recId);
      

    }
```

I am trying to load and save work order record. But its not executing.I am trying to load and save a work order record. but it's not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually like to simply return saved searches in getInputData because it's consistent to work with and you don't have to fuss with the going over 4k search results and having to return arrays of objects that you put together yourself. Usually transforming data to be in the format you want is best done in the map stage.

```js
/**
 * @NScriptType MapReduceScript
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */
define(["N/search", "N/record"], function (search, record) {
function getInputData() {
    // run a saved search of work orders
    return search.create({
        type: "workorder",
        filters: [
            ["type","anyof","WorkOrd"], 
            "AND", 
            ["mainline","is","T"], 
            "AND", 
            ["status","anyof","WorkOrd:A","WorkOrd:B","WorkOrd:D"]
        ],
        columns: [
            search.createColumn({name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"}),
        ]
    });    
}

function map(context) {
    
    // get the work order id
    var workOrderId = JSON.parse(context.value).id;    
    log.debug("workOrderId", workOrderId);
    
    // load the work order
    var wordOrderRecord = record.load({
        type: record.Type.WORK_ORDER,
        id: work_order_Id,
        isDynamic: true,
    });
    log.debug("wordOrderRecord", wordOrderRecord);
    
    // save the work order
    var recId = wordOrderRecord.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
    });
    log.debug("recId",recId);
}

function summarize(context) {
    // log any errors that might occur
    context.mapSummary.errors.iterator().each(function (_, errJson) {
        var error = JSON.parse(errJson);
        log.error({title: error.name, details: error.message});
        return true;
    });
}

return {
    getInputData: getInputData,
    map: map,
    summarize: summarize,
};
})
```

Comment: Hi, Steffen Andersland, Thanks for your response!

I am not getting any logs in return.

Comment: Hi Maira, logs are tricky in Map/Reduce Scripts. especially if you run into any errors. I recommend you add a summarize stage to your script and log all the errors that might occur. I added an example of what that would look like.

Comment: Hi Steffen Andersland, what code I should write in summarize stage?

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to log all the errors that might occur in your map stage using the summarize entrypoint.

Comment: Hi, I am getting error in log as:  Error TypeError 2/16/2023 6:22 am -System- Cannot call method "load" of undefined

Comment: Maira, the error is because you're not importing the "N/record" module. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I have already imported record module. When I put logs for record, I am not getting anything in record logs:  Debug record 2/16/2023 6:44 am -System-

Comment: Maira, the error you told me is being logged 'Cannot call method "load" of undefined' means that record isn't defined/imported. Can you update your question with the full script including the import and the define statement?

Comment: Hi Steffen, that error has been resolved. Actually I have not added modules sequentially. Now its working. Thanks a lot for your help and support :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working for you! Would you mind marking my answer as the correct answer if it helped you? :)

Comment: Yes sure! I have marked your answer as correct :)